# Cannot refresh token from google api OAuth2

Tags: php, google-oauth

Here is my php script `RefreshToken.php`

```
<?php
$url = 'https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token';
$post_data = array(
                    'code'          =>   'xxxxxxxx',
                    'client_id'     =>   'xxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'client_secret' =>   'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
                    'redirect_uri'  =>   'http://localhost/googleapi/AuthenticationCode.php',
                    'grant_type'    =>   'authorization_code',
                    );
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$token = json_decode($result);

echo $token->refresh_token . "\n";
?>
```

**Run PHP CLI**

php -q RefreshToken.php

PHP Notice:  Undefined property: stdClass::$refresh_token in /var/www/googleapi/RefreshToken.php on line 20

Comment: Do an echo on the $result ... My guess is that the $result is an array not an object ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `refresh_token` is not returned by default in Google OAuth2.

The request for an authorization code requires an extra parameter (`access_type`): then refresh token will be returned with access_token.

Other unusual behaviour: the `refresh_token` is returned only one time for a user. If, for some reason, `refresh_token` is lost for that user, then user will need to open [Google Account Security Settings page](https://security.google.com/settings/security/permissions?pli=1) and drop access for your app. And this is not enough: your app will need to pass more one params (`approval_prompt` equals `true`) to indicate we're forcing the request for a new `refresh_token`.

More info: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer#offline)